# Notify model item when QML List item is clicked

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I develop a small qt application using QML. I'd like to show a list of clickable items there. I have IssueHolder class derived from QObject to represent the item to visualize there. I created a model for such items

```
class IssuesModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    IssuesModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    const QList<IssueHolder*>& issues() const { return _issues; }

protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

private: //Members
    QList<IssueHolder*> _issues;
};
```

In the view class I set my model to the qml part like this

```
 _view = new QQuickView;    
_mainSetModel = new IssuesModel(this);
_view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("mainSetModel", _mainSetModel);
```

After that I created delegate in my QML file

```
 ListView {
    // Some properties here

    model: mainSetModel

    delegate: Item {
        // Some properties here

        IssueDelegate {                
            id: issuesDelegate

            // Some properties here

            signal pressed()

            MouseArea {
                onClicked: { issuesDelegate.pressed(); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to do something when my list item is clicked but I  don't want to implement the application logic in QML file. So I'd like to react on delegate click action so that if user click on some item on my list view corresponding IssueHolder instance will be notified. How can I do this?

Comment: What doesn't work with the code you have? You look like you're on the right track.

Comment: I don't know how should I connect issuesDelegate and IssueHolder. I want to change IssueHolder state when list item is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a `IssueHolder` role in your model:

```
enum {
    IssueHolderRole = Qt::UserRole
};
```

Then, reimplement [`roleNames()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames):

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> IssuesModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> names;
    names.insert(IssueHolderRole, "issueHolder");
    return names;
}
```

You'll also need to account for the new role in your `data()` function. The documentation has lots of examples of how to do this, but the gist of it is:

```
if (role == IssueHolderRole)
    return QVariant::fromValue(_issues.at(index.row()));
```

In `IssueHolder`, declare an invokable function or slot:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void doStuff();
```

In your delegate, respond to the click:

```
delegate: Item {
    // Some properties here

    IssueDelegate {                
        id: issuesDelegate

        // Some properties here

        MouseArea {
            onClicked: model.issueHolder.doStuff()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should `data()` function return for `IssueHolderRole`?

Comment: It should return `_issues.at(index.row())`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: OMG, I was so close to the solution! I wrote 
`if (role == IssueHolderRole)
{
    const IssueHolder *holder = _issues.at(index.row());
    return QVariant::fromValue(holder); 
}`
at the beginning but this code didn't compile.
Thanks a lot!